# Xamarin Forms Masterdetail menu height does not take whole screen height for certain devices

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why is that the master detail menu height is not taking the whole device screen space?

Here's a sample that I'm using for my menu:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="wrapper" BackgroundColor="Blue">
....
</StackLayout>
```

Here's the sample result:

[image]

You can see that the whole stack's height is occupying up to the status bar for Samsung 5.1.1 compared to Nexus 4.4.4 it doesn't. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: I think in your case it reaches to the top but the usb connected message covers it , try to run the app without connecting to USB

Comment: adding some text to the top of the StackLayout would confirm or contradict @BraveHeart 's theory

Comment: @BraveHeart I think that's not the case, even without the usb connected message it still doesn't go up in the status bar.

Comment: What about other apps ? try Gmail and Calendar. They both have MasterDetail page. In my case they go under the status bar but the bar becomes transparent.